# WPF binding is very slow when conversion exceptions occur

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a text box bound to a double property on a window, with `UpdateSourceTrigger` set to `PropertyChanged`. Typing text is noticeably slow when the content of the text box is no a valid number. Its a bit faster when running the executable directly outside visual studio. Strangely, it seems to be a a lot faster on my office machine even though they have similar specs.

Is it the conversion exceptions (which I can see logged in the output window) that are causing the slow response? I know that exceptions can slow a program down but surely not that much. I would expect the binding code catches the exception pretty close to where it is thrown so the stack would not need to be unwound too many levels. Should I somehow prevent the exception from occurring?
If so, I can think of a couple of ways to do it.

1. Bind the text box to string property
2. Implement a custom converter which converts to a 'default' value, say make my property a double? and set it to null when the value cannot be parsed.

Is there a better way?

Here is a minimal sample which shows the binding I am using.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp5"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        x:Name="_window" Title="MainWindow" Height="176.351" Width="404.73">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="73"
                 Text="{Binding Quantity, ElementName=_window, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='{}{0:#,0}'}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public double Quantity { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all the binding does not work this way. unless you declare Quantity as a DP or notify the property changes. second, I tried and it does not run slowly when exception occurs. please review your question.

Comment: However, in my opinion StringFormat is the best option if applicable.

Comment: Did you run it with the debugger attached? This may slow things down quite a bit, escpecially when exceptions are thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work for you.

```
private double quantity;
public string Quantity
{
    get { return quantity.ToString(); } // , StringFormat='{}{0:#,0}'
    set
    {
        if(quantity.ToString() != value)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                quantity = 0;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Quantity");
            }
            else
            {
                double temp;
                if (double.TryParse(value, out temp))
                {
                    quantity = temp;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Quantity");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```